# Split Sonar Scanner into Analysis and Code Coverage

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarscanner

we are running SonarQube with the maven Sonar Scanner Plugin. Everything works well so far in our GitLab-Pipeline.
Now I would like to improve the feedback-loop. So I thought about running the sonar-part with the code-analysis already parallel to the tests, whereas the code-coverage part can of course only be done after the tests have completed. But I couldn't find any documentation about this requirement. So do you know if and how this is possible?